# No default engine was specified and no extension was provided

Tags: nodejs, ejs

estoy aprendiendo [ejs](/questions/tagged/ejs) de node.js, pero al configurar el motor, renderizar y todo eso cuando lo ejecuto me sale este erro r

```
Error: No default engine was specified and no extension was provided.
    at new View (C:\Users\HP\Desktop\CrudApp\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:61:11)
    at Function.render (C:\Users\HP\Desktop\CrudApp\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:587:12)
    at ServerResponse.render (C:\Users\HP\Desktop\CrudApp\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1039:7)
    at C:\Users\HP\Desktop\CrudApp\server.js:18:9
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\HP\Desktop\CrudApp\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\HP\Desktop\CrudApp\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:144:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\HP\Desktop\CrudApp\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:114:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\HP\Desktop\CrudApp\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at C:\Users\HP\Desktop\CrudApp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:15
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\HP\Desktop\CrudApp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:346:12)
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Haciendo que cosa?? con que codigo???

Answer (score 0):

```
npm install Express
npm install ejs
```

incluir esta linea en el archivo principal

```
app.set("view engine", "ejs);
```

Answer (score 0):

el error se debe a que al instalar ejs debes definirlo en el app.js

para eso debes hacer:

```
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
```

// en caso de que trabajes con la carpeta src y el ejs se encuentre en una carpeta como por ejemple "views", debes definirlo por path

```
app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "./views");
```